# Set up environment variable ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I try many way to set up environment variables in ionic3:

> [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES IN IONIC 2](https://b-nova.com/ionic2/2017/04/01/environment-config-managenemt-ionic2.html)
>   [How to set up environment specific configurations with Ionic and Webpack](https://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2017/06/22/ionic-environments-webpack/)
>   [Ionic 2 Environment Variables: The Best Way](http://roblouie.com/article/296/ionic-2-environment-variables-the-best-way/)

But each solution failed on my project.
The `process.env.IONIC_ENV` is always equal to `dev` even if I do `ionic serve --prod` or something else.
I don't understand why... Am I doing something wrong or forget to do something? And by the way which of this solution is the more flexible?

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** use `ionic serve --prod`.

`ionic serve` starts a local dev server for app `dev/testing`.

If you need to test your app on `production` mode then you need to run below `CLI` command.After that, you can test your app on your `device` which has been attached to your PC using USB cable.

> ionic cordova run android --prod --device

Here is the list of options which you can do with [**ionic serve**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/)

This is for [**build CLI**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/)